can you make a key to open any door/follow-up question
a. Can you make a key to open any door?
b. Can you make a key that opens any door?
I can see three possible meanings:

Is there even one door you can make a key for?

Can you make a key that opens all doors?

Can you make a key for any door?


I don't think (b) can mean (3), but I am not sure. I am not even sure (a) can mean (3).
What are the possible meanings of (a) and (b)?
This is a follow up to a question I asked yesterday. Now the sentences are in the interrogative mood. I think things change here. Meaning (1) was not a possibility in the indicative mood.
Many thanks

Who is "you"?   A locksmith?  Or  an alternative to "one"?

Syntactically they are ambiguous because "can" can be used for both possibility and requesting.

Thank you both. Yes, a locksmith. But 'you' could also have a general meaning. Can one...
